# In Restlet, how can I get the Router instance from a ServerResource?

Tags: java, restlet

How can I get access to the Application's Router instance from my ServerResource class? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how I didn't find the answer to this when I asked the question... but it's pretty straightforward. In your "doInit" method you can do something like this:

```
Router myRouter = (Router)this.getApplication.getRoot();
```

Very simple!